# CSS Overlapping divs of equal size

Tags: html, css, position, absolute

I want a div on the top of another div. Before putting the position:absolute, the p's on the top div look great, but when I put the position:absolute, it shows the three p's in a straight line with no spaces between them.

How do I make this div with position:absolute to have the p's in different lines, like it is supposed to be?

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
<div class="box">
<p>Some text</p>

<div class="box-top">
<p>• Line 1</p>
<p>• Line 2</p>
<p>• Line 3</p>
</div>

</div>
```

Like I said before, I want a div ("box-top") on the top of another div ("box").

Comment: Just use `position: relative` on `.box` and `position: absolute` on `.box-top` then position it as you see fit with `top/left/right/bottom` and/or `transform: translate()` https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GEYmVK

Comment: @MichaelCoker thank you very much for the fast reply! But what if I want the white box to cover the black box, with the same width and height? And at the same time the three lines looking like that, one of the top of the other?

Comment: updated the codepen. You can use `top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%` or `top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;` https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GEYmVK

Comment: @MichaelCoker Please post your answer as an answer, not a comment :)

Comment: @Timothy I did.

Answer (score 0):

here's the answer. Hope this is what you are looking for.
One div has a black background. The overlapping div has a red background of opacity 50%.

**If your p render inline instead of one above each other, chances are you did not define your DOCTYPE or did not use the html tags in your html document => use this as a starter skeleton.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

Then here's the working example.

```css
.flex {
  display:-webkit-box; /*OLD-iOS 6-,Safari 3.1-6 */
  display:-moz-box;    /*OLD-Firefox 19*/
  display:-ms-flexbox; /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
  display:-webkit-flex;/* NEW - Chrome */
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.box {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1; /*iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
  -moz-box-flex: 1;  /* Firefox 19- */
  -webkit-flex: 1;          /* Chrome */
  -ms-flex: 1;              /* IE 10 */
  flex:1;
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}

.box-top {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1; /*iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
  -moz-box-flex: 1;  /* Firefox 19- */
  -webkit-flex: 1;          /* Chrome */
  -ms-flex: 1;              /* IE 10 */
  flex:1;
  position: relative;
  background: rgba(255,0,0,0.5); /* red */
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
<div class="box">
<p>Some text</p>
</div>
<div class="box-top">
<p>• Line 1</p>
<p>• Line 2</p>
<p>• Line 3</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you very much! But I still have no clue why my <p>'s keep showing one next to the other in one line, instead of one on top of the other, like your example. Is there some explanation for that? I have to do something with the <p> or the text in general?

Comment: Hey, as I don't have your CSS I don't know... Please edit your post and add your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is set `position: relative` on the parent and `position: absolute` on the child. If you want the child to occupy the size of the parent, I would use `top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;` for positioning.

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  height: 50vh;
}
.box-top {
  background: white;
  color: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <p>Some text</p>
  <div class="box-top">
    <p>• Line 1</p>
    <p>• Line 2</p>
    <p>• Line 3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Using flexbox instead of height: 50vh makes your height more dynamic.

Comment: @AstenMies what's your point? I just put a height for the demo. *"How do I make this div with position:absolute to have the p's in different lines, like it is supposed to be?"* The height of the parent has nothing to do with OP's problem.

Comment: Hey, no worries, just trying to help here. Many situations require the div's height to adjust with its content so I just thought it's good practice to anticipate that in the answer. Especially since our friend seems to be getting started with HTML. Cheers 

Comment: @AstenMies cool I just don't see the point of you commenting on my answer. Do you want me to change it or something? The height of the parent isn't relevant to their problem.

Comment: @AstenMies Hey, I'm not getting started with HTML. I only have a puntual problem with this <p> thing.